# AS3: Get event.localY of the clicked/tapped sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, events, touch, local, point

I have a sprite (let's call it CONTAINER) containing a few buttons (interactive sprites). I would like to retrieve the localY to know where the CONTAINER was touched/clicked. This is not a problem if the CONTAINER has mouseChildren = false;. But as soon as the buttons inside of it are active, the event.localY returns the value relative to the touched button.

```
_imageContainer.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);

private function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void {
    _imageContainer.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
    trace("Touch point.y: "+e.localY);
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the value of localY without setting mouseChildren = false or calculating it? (=getting the child's position and adding the value) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.localY` you can convert the global mouse coordinates to the local coordinates with `globalToLocal`

```
private function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent):void {
    _imageContainer.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
    var local:Point = _imageContainer.globalToLocal(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY));    
    trace("Touch point.y: "+point.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You Should use

```
localToGlobal();
```

or

```
globalToLocal();
```

See [as3 understanding localToGlobal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062209/flash-as3-understanding-localtoglobal)