# Get global coordinate of a dynamically created nested component?

Tags: actionscript-3, nested, sprite, global, private

In the code below, I have created 4 sprites (picn) inside a sprite (noteholder). How can I get the absolute values of the picn instances that I create? I know about the localToGlobal function, but I can't figure out how to use that in this case. At this point, I think I need the container because I need to be able to move the sprites after creation. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;
import Main;


public class Notes extends Sprite
{
    private var speed:int = 14;
    [Embed(source="../lib/Dodgethis.jpg")]
    private var picn:Class;
    private var noteholder:Sprite = new Sprite();


    public function appear() {
        trace ("appear ran")
        var arr1:Array = new Array;
        var numnotes:Number = 4;
        Main.StageRef.addChild(noteholder);
        trace (noteholder.x, noteholder.y);


        for (var i = 0; i < numnotes; i++)
            {
            //trace (i);
                var nbm:Bitmap = new picn;
                noteholder.addChild(nbm);
                nbm.y = i * 50;
                arr1.push(nbm);
```

Comment: Consider this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062209/flash-as3-understanding-localtoglobal

Comment: Thanks, but I can't reference the point I want to use the localToGlobal method on because it isn't created at runtime and I have no way to reference it by name (at least I can't figure out how to reference them by name due to variable scope)

Comment: Given your code above you can reference these bitmaps two ways — either via the array like `arr1[0]` or from the sprite `noteholder.getChildAt(0)` — you should probably prefer `arr1` and you should probably scope it to the object and rename it `noteSprites` or something clearer. You don't need really need to mess around with naming dynamically created displayobjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hold a reference to the display objects you dynamically create — you don't need a "name" which is just an abstraction of instance variables when creating visual assets in the Flash IDE.

I've updated your code to demonstrate the concept:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage; // added this
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle; // added this (see below)
import Main;

public class Notes extends Sprite
{
    private var speed:int = 14;
    [Embed(source="../lib/Dodgethis.jpg")]
    private var NoteBMP:Class;
    private var display:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var notes:Array = []; // make notes an instance variable, so it's accessible throughout the class

    // I renamed appear to 'build' because I'm a pedantic moron
    public function build():void
    {
        trace ("build ran");
        var noteCount:int = 4;
        Main.StageRef.addChild(display);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < noteCount; i++)
        {
            var nbm:Bitmap = new NoteBMP;
            display.addChild(nbm);
            nbm.y = i * 50;
            notes.push(nbm); // by adding the display objects to an array you can reference them later
```

then at some later point in the Notes class you can reference your bitmaps by looping through the `notes` array

```
// initialize variables outside the loop
var localPos:Point 
var globalPos:Point;
var bounds:Rectangle;
var n:DisplayObject;
var stage:Stage = Main.StageRef;

for (var i:int = 0; i < notes.length; i++)
{
    trace( 'note' + i );
    n = notes[i] as DisplayObject; // cast during assignment since array items have ambiguous type

    // getBounds() returns a Rectangle representing the bounding box of the display object
    bounds = n.getBounds(stage);
    trace(
        'getBounds:',
        bounds.top, bounds.left, bounds.bottom, bounds.right
    );

    // localToGlobal() returns a Point which is just the position
    localPos = new Point( n.x, n.y );
    globalPos = display.localToGlobal(localPos)
    trace(
        'localToGlobal:',
        globalPos.x, globalPos.y
    );
}
```

A few points:

1. I refactored some names to make the intention more clear
2. I wonder why your `Notes` class extends Sprite, since it adds `display` (what you called "noteholder") to the stage. Assuming that's correct just make Notes a generic object i.e. doesn't seem to need to extend another class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getBounds  [about getBounds](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29)

```
// call this after added to stage
if (stage) {
     var r:Rectangle = nbm.getBounds(stage);// r's x and y is the global pos
}
```

And I think localToGlobal should work in your case. Move the sprites don't have effect on localToGlobal

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work for me. If I typed it in exactly as you have it, nothing happened. The script never ran. When I took out the if (stage) it ran, but the y values were all 0, which doesn't help me at all. Have any idea what else to try?

Comment: See my comment above and try `noteSprites[0].getBounds(Main.StageRef)`