# (Actionscript 3) Pixel-perfect collision detection between the walls and player?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make a flash game in which there is collision detection between the player and the walls. However, when I try using Wall11.hitTestPoint(), I cannot get the collision detection to be perfect. Then, I decided to use bitmap but it is hard to code this because the wall is irregularly shaped (it is not a square, rectangle, circle or any regular shape). Is there anyway to improve the collision detection with walls?

```
function checkCollision(_debug:Boolean = false):Boolean {           
        var bmd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(Wall11.width, Wall11.height, true, 0);
        var bmd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(LevelOnePlayer.width, LevelOnePlayer.height, true, 0);

        bmd1.draw(Wall11);
        bmd2.draw(LevelOnePlayer);

        if (_debug) {
            var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd1);
            bmp.x = Wall11.x;
            bmp.y = Wall11.y;
            addChild(bmp);

            var bmp2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd2);
            bmp2.x = LevelOnePlayer.x;
            bmp2.y = LevelOnePlayer.y;
            addChild(bmp2);
        }
        if(bmd1.hitTest(new Point(Wall11.x, Wall11.y), 255, bmd2, new Point(LevelOnePlayer.x, LevelOnePlayer.y), 255))
        return true;
        if (!_debug) {
            bmd1.dispose();
            bmd2.dispose();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why hitTestPoint (with the last argument shapeFlag=true) does not work for you?

Comment: No matter what I set the point to, the wall always detects collision when the player is either too close or too far away from the wall. I do not know how to set the collision to the point where I want the collision point to be.

Comment: Again, to rule that out. Do you use shapes and shape flag? Also, do you use stage coordinates for the point, or local coordinates?

Comment: Sorry but what are shapes and shape flags? I also do not know the difference between stage coordinates and local coordinates. Can you send me a link/code?

Comment: I posted an answer below so you can start with it.

Answer (score 0):

These are basics of hitTestPoint stuff.

```
package 
{
    import flash.geom.Point;

    import flash.events.Event;

    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;

    public class HitTest extends Sprite
    {
        private var textArea:TextField;
        private var Circle:Shape;
        private var Box:Shape;

        public function HitTest()
        {
            if (stage) onStage();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
        }

        private function onStage(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.stageFocusRect = false;

            addShapes();
            addLabel();
            onFrame();

            // Call it every frame to keep things updated.
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
        }

        private function onFrame(e:Event = null):void
        {
            // Place graphics to the center of the stage.
            x = stage.stageWidth >> 1;
            y = stage.stageHeight >> 1;

            // Lets detect collision with the circle.
            var aPoint:Point = new Point();

            // Take local mouse coordinates within the target shape.
            aPoint.x = Circle.mouseX;
            aPoint.y = Circle.mouseY;

            // Convert them into the root coordinates - it is the ONLY correct way.
            // Comment the next 2 lines to see how local coordinates fail to work.
            aPoint = Circle.localToGlobal(aPoint);
            aPoint = root.globalToLocal(aPoint);

            // Hit test the point against shape.
            // Set the last parameter to false to see hitTest against the shape bounding box.
            var aHit:Boolean = Circle.hitTestPoint(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, true);

            textArea.text = aHit? "! HIT !": "NO HIT";
        }

        private function addShapes():void
        {
            Circle = new Shape();
            Circle.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000, 1);
            Circle.graphics.beginFill(0xCC99FF, 1);
            Circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
            Circle.graphics.endFill();

            Box = new Shape();
            Box.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0xCCCCCC, 1);
            Box.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);

            addChild(Box);
            addChild(Circle);
        }

        private function addLabel():void
        {
            textArea = new TextField();

            textArea.x = 10;
            textArea.y = 10;
            textArea.width = 70;
            textArea.height = 20;

            textArea.border = true;
            textArea.wordWrap = false;
            textArea.multiline = true;
            textArea.selectable = true;
            textArea.background = true;
            textArea.mouseEnabled = false;

            var aFormat:TextFormat;

            aFormat = textArea.getTextFormat();
            aFormat.font = "_typewriter";
            aFormat.size = 12;
            aFormat.bold = true;
            aFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;

            textArea.setTextFormat(aFormat);
            textArea.defaultTextFormat = aFormat;

            stage.addChild(textArea);
            textArea.text = "NO HIT";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I have not replied in a month. Anyway, thanks for your help. It is not clear to me on this part though: What does Circle.mouseX mean?

Comment: @GaryLuKOTH Local mouse coordinates within the Circle coordinate system. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062209/flash-as3-understanding-localtoglobal and http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/06/22/understanding-as3-localtoglobal-method/ for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand how your code works. Now, I just need to know how I can find the collision detection between different shapes, besides just the mouse.

Comment: @GaryLuKOTH In the exactly same way, but you take certain hero-releated point (e.g. its center) for the origin instead of mouse.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I got the shapes to detect when they are hitting each other. Now, what code do I write so that the objects cannot overlap? Like, I want the wall to block the square. How do I do that?

Comment: The simpler way is to save hero position temporarily, move it, check if it has bumped into an obstacle, then reset it to the original position if so. If nothing is hit then new position is valid.