# HitTestObject distance bug between two object

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a car game which is drive reverse.The game over when enemy and car hit each other.I have problem with collision.
Car and enemy hit when they get close each other,but they have still big space in there.

Please check this image.
https://s8.postimg.cc/p85w0wm2t/image.gif

I use this code.

```
if(dubageri1.hitTestObject(carMC)){
    dubageri1.gotoAndPlay(2);


    geribas.gericarpti = true;


    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,engeller1geri1lev1)

}
```

Also I tried something like this.But this time collision has late.

```
var nDistX:Number = Math.abs ( carMC.x - dubageri1.x );
var nDistY:Number = Math.abs ( carMC.y - dubageri1.y );
var nDistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( nDistX * nDistX + nDistY * nDistY );

var sDistx:Number = Math.abs ( carMC.x - dubageri1.x );
var sDisty:Number = Math.abs ( carMC.y - dubageri1.y );
var nsistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( sDistx * sDistx + sDisty * sDisty );


 collect.text=String(nDistance);    

if ( nDistance < 120 )
                {
                    trace("aha");
                    dubageri1.gotoAndPlay(2);
                    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dsaa);
                }
```

Note:My objects was made as vector.

Does anybody tell me what im doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

```
var aPoint:Point = new Point();
aPoint = carMC.localToGlobal(aPoint);

var bPoint:Point = new Point();
bPoint = dubageri1.localToGlobal(bPoint);


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ilkcikis);
function ilkcikis(event:Event) {





    bPoint = root.globalToLocal(bPoint);

    var zHit:Boolean = carMC.hitTestPoint(bPoint.x, bPoint.y, true);
    textbaba.text = zHit? "! HIT !": "NO HIT";




    carMC.x=mouseX;
    carMC.y=mouseY;


}
```

Comment: The **hitTestObject** method collides two objects via their respective bounding boxes, which can intersect even if these two objects of yours are visually distanced. If you turn off everything but these two objects and turn on the **right click > show redraw regions** option in the debug player, you will see for yourself.

Comment: Here's a good illustration: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/--req4IMi4bQ/UE9gDomR1yI/AAAAAAAAAQ4/NzaBY32Zfy4/s1600/boundingBox.png

Comment: I think I did what you mentioned with "flash.profiler.showRedrawRegions(true)" and I got the borders right now.Here is the pic.https://s8.postimg.cc/hngnanfs5/BOXA.png But what is the solution for that ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you did the thing. The solution I came up with years ago (might not be the only one) is to outline the shapes of the objects with a contour of points and to cross-**hitTestPoint** them (keep in mind that this operation requires the global point coordinates so you will need **localToGlobal** method) against each other with **shapeFlag** argument set to **true**. That allows to test the real object shapes. AS3 is fast enough to process, probably, thousands of such **hitTestPoint**s a frame before being encumbered.

Comment: Thank you for the idea.I also check the BitmapData.

Comment: **BitmapData** will require to be **draw**ed every frame, and you will still have to check pixel values by some coordinates. I think this way is more troublesome for you and more cumbersome for Flash Player.

Comment: localToGlobal new method for me I'll learn but I can't find the right examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42216463/4687633

Comment: Thank you.Now I can get the local point of objects.But still I can't figure out how can I collect detection to each other.Update first messsage.

Comment: As I said above (I definitely said that) you need to mark a **contour** for each of the objects (not just a single center point), then you are to **hitTestPoint** the whole contour (each point of the contour in a loop) of object A against object B and vice versa **every frame**. Just a single hit would mean a collision, no hits would mean none.

Comment: Can you check last time please.I have a collision now,but it does when only contact to center of the object.

Comment: Because you **hitTestPoint** only the center point. Do you understand what **border** or **contour** is? You need to form a list (an **Array**) of border points and hit test **all of them** against the other object.